# Why \graphicspath doesn't work?

Tags: graphics, pdftex, texlive

I'm using pdftex with texlive in a Rmarkdown script to append a `header.tex` file to my reports. I'm trying to use the following `.tex`:

```
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{eso-pic,graphicx,transparent}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} %
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[R]{Relatório emitido pelo SOMA - Sistema de Observação, Monitoramento e Ação}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\pagestyle{fancy}}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\graphicspath{{~/somadb/soma-reports/Rmd/}}
\AddToShipoutPictureFG{
\put(0,0){%
\AtStockCenter{%
\makebox[0pt]{%
\centering
  {\transparent{0.8} \includegraphics[width=0.95\paperwidth,height=0.95\paperheight, valign=c, %
keepaspectratio]{test.png}}%
  }
  }
}}
```

But it gives me the error:

> Error: Package pdftex.def Error: File `test.png' not found

I tried remove the `{test.png}` to `{~/somadb/soma-reports/Rmd/test.png}` and it worked nicely.

The `test.png` is in the same folder of my `.tex`, just for information.

Comment: `\string~` or safer `/home/wherever/your/home/is/somadb`  but better still would be to have a path relative to your document, using an absolute path makes the document intrinsically non-portable.

Comment: If your images are in the same folder just remove `\graphicspath` it is doing nothing useful in that case.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  Would `~/` even be resolved?

Comment: @daleif kpse has some support for `~` in at least some OS but not if latex expands it to `\nobreakspace {}`

Comment: The problem is, if I remove the `\graphicspath` it doesn't work even with the image being in the same folder as my `.tex`. Maybe is something with TexLive, but I don't know what...

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned, using `\graphicspath{{~/somadb/soma-reports/Rmd/}}` is probably not necessary here.  My advice would be to use a relative path instead such as `\graphicspath{{path/to/images/}}`.  My recommendation is to remove the `\graphicspath{}` command as you have stated that the image is in the working directory;

```
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{eso-pic,graphicx,transparent}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} %
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[R]{Relatório emitido pelo SOMA - Sistema de Observação, Monitoramento e Ação}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\pagestyle{fancy}}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\AddToShipoutPictureFG{
\put(0,0){%
\AtStockCenter{%
\makebox[0pt]{%
\centering
  {\transparent{0.8} \includegraphics[width=0.95\paperwidth,height=0.95\paperheight, valign=c, %
keepaspectratio]{test.png}}%
  }
  }
}}
```

Another option is to place all your images in a folder of their own called whatever you want (e.g. `img/`) and then define `\graphicspath{img/}`

```
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{eso-pic,graphicx,transparent}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} %
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[R]{Relatório emitido pelo SOMA - Sistema de Observação, Monitoramento e Ação}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\pagestyle{fancy}}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\graphicspath{{img/}}
\AddToShipoutPictureFG{
\put(0,0){%
\AtStockCenter{%
\makebox[0pt]{%
\centering
  {\transparent{0.8} \includegraphics[width=0.95\paperwidth,height=0.95\paperheight, valign=c, %
keepaspectratio]{test.png}}%
  }
  }
}}
```

Comment: Hmm... So my texlive config is with something wrong since when I remove the `graphicspath` and just let the test.png it gives me the same error:
`Error: Package pdftex.def Error: File `test.png' not found`

Comment: @Luiz Can you try to compile with `--shell-escape` like `pdflatex --shell-escape yourfile` please?  Also what OS are you using? More information is always helpful.